# Mysql - accessing two databases in different locations in same server

Tags: mysql, database

Is it possible for a mysql server instance to access one database in hard disk and another database sitting in flash memory? I am running this mysql instance in a linux box where i need to need to maintain one database in flash memory and another in my harddisk. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MySQL documentation for create database tells:

*A database in MySQL is implemented as a directory containing files that correspond to tables in the database. Because there are no tables in a database when it is initially created, the CREATE DATABASE statement creates only a directory under the MySQL data directory and the db.opt file.*

So there is an directory for the database after executing create database. You just need to mount the flash memory as this directory and copy everything into it.

Comment: Sorry for not making it clearer. I mean, i need to create 2 different Databases in different hard-disks/Volumes? That is if I have hard-disks HDD_1 and HDD_2. I need to maintain 2 different databases namely Database_1 in HDD_1 and Database_2 in HDD_2. Is this possible?

Comment: Your question was clear. You know how Linux/Unix manages your filesystems with mountpoints? In short: Linux has a single directory tree (not Drive a: b:...). You can mount any harddisk into any directory. So if your database directory is something like "/usr/mysql/databases" you can have a directory "/usr/mysql/databases/database1" on HDD_1, and you can mount HDD_2 to "/usr/mysql/databases/database2". Then this directory and its contents are stored on HDD_2 but it is completely transparent and appears as part if the system directory tree on HDD_1. Now clearer?

Answer (score 0):

a very similar thing can be done using symlinks instead of mount points
I think that symlinks are simpler and more flexible

someming like:
create database (or 2)
cd /some/path/mysql/

there is your DBNAME directory

mv DBNAME /some/other/place/where/you/want/it/DBNAME
ln -s /some/other/place/where/you/want/it/DBNAME DBNAME

(doublecheck on permissions that mysql sever has/needs vv. this new symlink)

should work